# jQuery -Cycle2 plugin to change slides on anchor only

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

Im using Cycle2 plugin in order to create custom reference list. Switching slides should be activated only when link with anchor is clicked.
Right now it work no matter if there is anchor or not (try clicking "Ref 3 without anchor" or "Ref 4 without anchor").

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="references-list" class="cycle-pager external">
    <li><a href="">Ref 1 with image</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ref 2 with image</a></li>
    <li>Ref 3 without anchor</li>
    <li>Ref 4 without anchor</li>
    <li>Ref 5 should bring 3th slide</li>
</ul>
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-pager="#references-list"
    data-cycle-pager-template="">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qz1vqkjy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want all elements in the pager to react I would suggest removing the pager option from the slideshow and creating your own pager code.

Following uses a `data-` attribute to define which image to reference (by index)

HTML

```
<li><a href="" data-img="0">Ref 1 with image</a></li>
```

JS for paging

```
$('#references-list a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle( $(this).data('img'));
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qz1vqkjy/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Sweet! Clever thinking.